# Can I create a DVD from a video-ts folder

Tags: windows, macos, dvd

I have a `VIDEO-TS` folder with some `BUP, IFO` and `VOB` files.

Is it possible to create a DVD from this folder? 
What programs could I use.

Both Mac and Windows are OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a technical sense, the VIDEO_TS folder already contains the video data in DVD format.  A Video DVD is the contents of this VIDEO_TS folder burned onto a DVD+/-R disc in a hybrid ISO9660+UDF filesystem.  See [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/55982/what-is-the-necessary-file-structure-for-a-dvd-to-be-playable) for more on what the folder contains.

If you already have the VIDEO_TS, you do not need an encoding tool.  Many data burning utilities can create Video DVDs, but you need to make sure they don't try to burn as a data DVD -- data DVDs won't necessarily lay out the files in the proper order, and may use the wrong filesystem for the disc.

If you have the `mkisofs` command available (in the Terminal on MacOSX and Linux, or Windows with Cygwin), or the `hdiutil` command on OSX, you can make a ready-to-burn ISO with one of the following commands ([source](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070612161317338), from [Davide's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/109166/can-i-create-a-dvd-from-a-video-ts-folder/109171#109171)):

```
# INPUT_FOLDER is the folder that contains the VIDEO_TS

mkisofs -f -dvd-video -udf -V VOLUMENAME -o OUTPUT.iso /path/to/INPUT_FOLDER

hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -udf -udf-version 1.02 -default-volume-name "VOLUMENAME" -o OUTPUT.iso /path/to/INPUT_FOLDER
```

The output ISO file can be burned with any burning utility program.

Comment: The programs named below are nice too, but the command line comes pre-installed (OK, not on Windows)...

Answer (score 2):

**[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)** is a free, portable and open source program that can create Video DVDs in Windows.

Go to **File** > **New Project** > **DVD Video Disc...**

[image]

Drag the Video_TS folder into the **Disc Layout** window, then go to **Actions** > **Burn Compilation** > **to a Compact Disc...**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Ashampoo Free](http://download.cnet.com/Ashampoo-Burning-Studio-Free/3000-2646_4-10776287.html) as well. :) Just goto > Burn Movies > From a prepared folder then browse to the video ts folder. :)

Answer (score 1):

Under OSX I think [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) can do that.
Or see [this trick](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070612161317338) for a command line solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think Nero could do that in Windows. Maybe you can search for an encoder for VOB files. So you can convert VOB to AVI or MPGEG, and than burn it with Nero or an other burning tool.